# PDO Exception with Laravel 4 php artisan migrate command on EC2 AWS

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-4

I have an ubuntu 12.04 instance on EC2 in AWS and a Laravel 4 Project uploaded there.  I am trying to run php artisan migrate, but for some reason I cannot connect to my mysql server through the command.  I am able to get into the MySql DB on SQL Pro just find using SSH (using the elastic ip as host).  I also SSH into the server using Elastic IP.

I get this error when I run php artisan migrate:

```
[PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '**.***.***.**' (11  
  1)                                                                           



migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

Where the starts represent my "elastic IP", which is the host I use to connect to mySQL in SQL Pro.

In my database.php config file, I am connecting using:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '*ELASTIC IP*',
            'database'  => 'dbname',
            'username'  => '****',
            'password'  => '*******',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

I have installed php5, apache2, mcrypt, and php5-mysql on this server.  How do I solve this issue?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not necessarily allowing your 'user' into the database.

In MySQL the 'user' is a combination of `'username'@'hostname'`. It could be that you are just allowing your `username` for a particular host which could be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. To see if this is the problem you can create a user with the hostname wildcard `%`. Also, by allowing that user to all databases. From the `mysql>` command line like this:

```
CREATE USER '<username>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<username>'@'%';
```

Comment: Should I use my elastic ip in place of the %?

Comment: It all depends on where you are connecting from. Where are you connecting from?

Comment: I get into my server with ssh using the ubuntu@elastic_ip...I'm not really sure what you mean.  I just want to know what credentials to use to log into my mysql db in my laravel project so I can run artisan commands.

Comment: Is your database and your Laravel application on the same machine?

Comment: yes, both on ubuntu instance on Aamazon Web Services EC2

Comment: So you want to allow '<username>'@'localhost' and '<username>'@'127.0.0.1'

Comment: No, this is not localhost...this is the elastic ip of the LIVE server.

Comment: yeah, exactly, but the application is connecting to the database on the same host in EC2.

Comment: yes, ok?  Are my credentials above in the question correct?

Comment: Looks ok. I believe it's more of `GRANT` issue for the user you are connecting as

Comment: I'm as the root user.  Shouldn't that have all permissions?

Comment: Sounds like we are going in circles here. Yes, `root` should allow you to see everything.  I won't be able to tell without looking at it.